# About Tier of BigQuery Flatrate

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

BigQuery is now available for Tier 100 at Tier 1 rate.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes

Will this also apply to Flatrate?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this of Google rather than stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

Compute tiers are irrelevant for flat rate reservations. For on-demand queries, compute tiers 1-100 are now treated as the same thing (you won't pay any extra).